# Get Discord Token Using Puppeteer

Tags: discord, puppeteer, token

Trying to get my Discord token using puppeteer. "token returns null" other properties return values. Strange behavior. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    await page.evaluate(() => {

        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

        iframe.onload = async function () {
            var localStorage = iframe.contentWindow.localStorage;
            console.log(localStorage);
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));
        };
        iframe.src = 'about:blank';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    })
```

I tried making an iframe where the local storage is console logging in dev console however the token will not. I would like to know why this is and if there is any kind of work around.

Comment: I got this working by adding a short delay before evaluating the page.